# Last login time with Glassfish and OpenDS - LDAP credentials cached?

Tags: ldap, glassfish, glassfish-3, jaas, opends

I have configured Glassfish 3.0 to use an OpenDS 2.2 directory for user authentication using the ldap realm. User authentication works fine (I'm using a web application with form-login configured), however I have noticed the following behaviour and I can't understand what's causing it:

- my OpenDS server is configured to track user's last login time using attribute ds-pwp-last-login-time (as configured in the users' password policy); the first time a user logs in after Glassfish startup, the ds-pwp-last-login-time attribute is correctly set, however the attribute is not updated after every subsequent successful login
- after restarting Glassfish or disabling/enabling the web application I'm using, the attribute ds-pwp-last-login-time is again set correctly the first time a user logs in, but it is then never set again

I believe the possible causes of this are either:

- during first login after server/application restart, a step is carried out by the server that causes the ds-pwp-last-login-time attribute to be updated, however this is not the case for subsequent logins
- Glassfish keeps a local cache of the users that have already authenticated to the server using the ldap realm

I've inspected the server log setting the security logger to FINEST and I found that during the first login for each single user, the following lines are outputed

```
....
[Web-Security] Policy Context ID was: MyApp/MyApp|#]
[Web-Security] Generating a protection domain for Permission check.|#]
[Web-Security] Checking with Principal : testuser|#]
[Web-Security] Checking with Principal : TestRole|#]
[Web-Security] Checking with Principal : dc=groups|#]
[Web-Security] Checking with Principal : dc=test|#]
[Web-Security] Checking with Principal : dc=com|#]
[Web-Security] Codesource with Web URL: file:/MyApp/MyApp|#]
...
```

Does anyone know how to configure Glassfish/OpenDS so that the ds-pwp-last-login-time attribute is correctly set after every successful login? Does anyone know what the section *Generating a protection domain for Permission check* shown in the server log is doing?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check in the OpenDS access log if there is a Bind request for each time the user logs in. If not, that means there is some caching in GlassFish.
The other thing to look at is the ds-cfg-last-login-time-format attribute part of the Password Policy. The default is to capture the last login time with a Day of resolution. So the last-login-time only changes if the login occurs on the next day (usually defeating tests).

Ludo

Comment: Hi Ludo, 
thank you for the hint, I've checked the OpenDS log and as expected the BIND operation is performed by Glassfish only during the user's first login attempt. This is also confirmed in this post http://forums.java.net/node/700923.
I had already specified the ds-cfg-last-login-time-format attribute to use hours/minutes/seconds.

The best solution would be to configure the ldap connection timeout in Glassfish, however as I have been unable to find how this can be done, I have set the OpenDS idle connection timeout to a low number to force GF to bind the user again.

Comment: For information, the idle connection timeout can be configured in OpenDS using ds-config-idle-time-limit